# Android Studio execution failed for task 'app\build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\debug\jars\3\1f\main.jar'.'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-proguard

I updated android studio from 2.1.2 to 2.3 and and gradle from 2.14.1 to 3.4.
After I run my project I am encountering the following error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Failed to read zip file 'D:\MyAndroidProject\app\build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\debug\jars\3\1f\main.jar'.
```

Any feedback is welcomed

Comment: rebuild project from Project menu and test again.

Comment: Nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem when i updated Android Studio 2.3 and Gradle to 3.3.

When I use Proguard examples dictionary (like: `proguard\examples\dictionaries\keywords.txt`), it builds successfully. It seems   the dictionary file only can use ASCII characters after this update

my solution:

1. Change you dictionary file to only use ASCII.
2. If there's an error

   > Unable to delete file:`app\build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\debug\jars\3\1f\main.jar`

   then restart Android Studio
3. If there's an error:

   > java.io.IOException: Failed to read zip file `app\build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\debug\jars\3\1f\main.jar`

   then rebuild the project. If the rebuild doesn't work then restart Android Studio and rebuild the project.

Comment: How do I change dictionary file?

Answer (score 1):

go to your application folder -> app folder -> build folder
and remove all content inside.
back to your android studio, and it will work

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in the gradle plugin, try to downgrade used plugin:
In project level build.gradle use gradle plugin version 2.2.3 - it works for me:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}
```

Restart Android studio after change and it should works.